# Mongodb doesn't respond

Tags: replication, performance, mongodb

We have a sharded cluster with 3 shards. The version is: 3.6.13. The users of the prod. database (1,8 TB sized) complain about an issue.
System works normally but after sometime it stucks and doesn't respond. During that time we don't see any long running queries. Everything seems normal in the log files. 
But when we track the network the requests are coming to Mongos, Mongos sends them to mongod but shards don't send back anything in network level.
The single qlue that I catch is about oplog entries. When I took a dump backup with oplog, in dump log it has "dumped 7757639 oplog entries"
In the dumps I took last week there was only 1 dumped entry. Is there a problem with the replication that causes waits?

When I check the replication status, it seems there is no problem.
Thank you for your replies.

Comment: Investigate connPoolStats (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/connPoolStats/) when the issue occurs, on every mongos and mongod. Post results in the question.

Comment: Thank you, for your reply. We lived the issue again. And the connPoolStats are the same with the non-problematic time.

Comment: from mongos "numClientConnections" : 17,
 "numAScopedConnections" : 0,
 "totalInUse" : 0,
 "totalAvailable" : 32,
 "totalCreated" : 5418,
 "totalRefreshing" : 0,
 "pools" : {
  "NetworkInterfaceASIO-TaskExecutorPool-3" : {
   "poolInUse" : 0,
   "poolAvailable" : 3,
   "poolCreated" : 1052,
   "poolRefreshing" : 0,
   "xxx:port" : {
    "inUse" : 0,
    "available" : 1,
    "created" : 278,
    "refreshing" : 0